# For Version 1.2.2 of Apache IoTDB, why did `later request in same group will be redirected` error occurred?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Has anyone ever encountered the problem `session insertRecords fail: later request in same group will be redirected` in Version 1.2.2 of Apache IoTDB? I encountered this reminder when the time series data is writing into IoTDB, and I do not know what action made this error happened. Anyone have any clues on the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This log is printed after the `enableRedirection` of `session` is manually turned off in Apache IoTDB. Under normal circumstances, `enableRedirection` does not need to be turned off, so this warning log does not affect the normal writing of data into IoTDB. In the latest Version 1.3.0 of IoTDB, this log has been deleted.